# Redirect button with progressbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

I'm wondering how to combine button and progress bar to achieve something close to *next badge* button on stackoverflow site. Here is what I've tried <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhvgyq4j/)**</kbd>:

```html
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="padding: 30px;">
    <div class="progress" style="width:170px; height:25px;">
    <a class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning"
         role="progressbar" 
         aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" 
         aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 30%;">
        <span class="sr-only">30% Complete</span>
                Show
    </a>
</div>
```

Text located on the left part and whole construction doesn't act as a button (only text). In other words how can I convert first one to another?

[image]=>
[image]

Comment: What you're basically asking for is how to implement a modal window?

Comment: @Gustaf No - just want to combine link, button (with centered caption) and progressbar in one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mbpsxmmv/2/).

HTML:

```
<div style="padding: 30px; width: 250px;">
    <a href="#here-comes-your-link">
    <div class="progress p-style">
        <div class="progress-bar pb-style" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%"></div>
            <span class="show">Fanatic</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pb-style {
    background: #FFCC00;    
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
.p-style {
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #FFCC00;
    position: relative;
}
.progress span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #222;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately with low percent (width) text placed too far from center of progressbar/button.